# How can I pass dynamic object properties to directives in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a problem. I want to pass a variable through an attribute `part="header"` to a directive.

This works:
`ng-mouseleave="$parent.editing.header = isEditing()"`

This does NOT work:
`ng-mouseleave="$parent.editing.{{part}} = isEditing()"`

It produces the same output in the code, but it does not trigger.
I'm using an isolate scope as this:

```
scope: {
  part: '@'
}
```

How should I solve this?

Comment: ))))
$parent['editing'][part] = isEditing()

Comment: @KoIIIeY Nope, that doesn't work.